# UIImageView roate, in addition to zoom inside UISCrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, rotation

I need to develop a utility screen, where user can take a photo, and crop out a square out of it. This would in turn would need to let the user to adjust the photo, by swiping, rotating & zooming in/out as needed.

I have been so far able to achieve zoom plus swipe. The complete code can be downloaded from the following drop box URL.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj3xr5z4l5lrpjz/SquareCapture.zip?dl=0

I need help on rotating, cant seem to get it working I have tried applying `UIRotationGestureRecongizer`

Comment: What doesn't work exactly with UIRotationGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I looked into your code. You should refuse using UIScrollView in your case and use UIPinchGestureRecognizer, UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIRotateGestureRecognizer. Good luck